# How to run setTimeout() with a random interval in each iteration in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to iterate over a string array with a delay of a few milliseconds every step of iteration. Something like below -

```
var l = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var delay = 5000;
for(var i = 0;i < l.lenght;i++) {
    document.querySelectorAll("a[title='" + l[i] + "']")[0].parentNode.children[0].click();
    delay = 5000 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000) + 1;
   **<WAIT for 'delay' number of milliseconds**
}
```

I've been able to convert the code to below using setTimeout() method -

```
var i = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    if (i < l.length) {
        document.querySelectorAll("a[title='" + l[i] + "']")[0].parentNode.children[0].click();
       i++;
   }
   else {
      clearInterval(interval);
   }
   //delay = 5000 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000) + 1); **NOT SURE where to change the delay variable**
}, delay);
```

But the delay variable essentially becomes a constant once setTimeout kicks off. How to change the delay variable in each iteration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a recursive timer function for this:

Try the following :

```js
function displayValue(){
  
  let arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
  let delay = 1000;  
  let i = 0;
  
  function timerFunction(i){
     if(i === arr.length)
      return;
      setTimeout(()=>{
        console.log(arr[i]);
        i++;
        timerFunction(i);
      }, delay);
      delay = delay + 1000 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 4000);
  } 
  
  timerFunction(i);
}

displayValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you try replacing that delay variable with a function such as this?

```
var i = 0;
var interval = setInterval(
function() {
  if (i < l.length) {
    document.querySelectorAll("a[title='" + l[i] + "']")[0].parentNode.children[0].click();
    i++;
  }
  else {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
},
function() {
  return 5000 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000) + 1;
}
);
```

Comment: Thank you. Will it change the delay in every iteration though? If so, this is probably the simplest solution. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval`, which you have used in your example, initializes a callback launching every (circa) N ms, where N is fixed. You have to clear it later on with `clearInterval`.

`setTimeout` on the other hand means - invoke my callback after ~N time. You could then call another `setTimeout` inside the callback, with a different N.

as an example:

```
function callback() {
  /* 
    your logic here
  */
  delay = 5000 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000) + 1);
  setTimeout(callback, delay); // for your "clearInterval" case - just don't invoke this
}

setTimeout(callback, initialDelay);
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Yes, I mentioned setTimeout() in my example by mistake, now I see that my initial approach using setInterval() would never have worked.

Answer (score 0):

This thread appears the closest I found to the fundamental question of how to iterate through an array at a random time interval, which isn't as easy as one would think.
Although arguably a little general for the specific question asked, the currently accepted answer looks the closest match to the fundamental question. The code below is a minor modification which looks to provide a random delay on the first pass and logs each random delay after the logging each array value.

```
function displayValue(){

    let arr = ['a', 'b', 'c','d', 'e'];
      let delay = Math.floor(Math.random()*10000);  
      let i = 0;
      
      function timerFunction(i){
         if(i === arr.length)
          return;
          setTimeout(()=>{
            console.log(arr[i]);
            console.log(`delay was ${Math.floor(delay/1000)} seconds`);
            i++;
            timerFunction(i);
          }, delay);
          delay = Math.floor(Math.random()*10000);
      } 
      
      timerFunction(i);
    }
    
    displayValue();
```

The value of the above modification probably depends on the context.

Interestingly, applying the introduction to *forEach* from bootcamp provides an alternate solution which is probably closer related to the OP!

```
var colors = ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow"];

function printArr(x){
    var random = Math.round(Math.random()*60000);
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(x);
        console.log(`Delay was ${Math.floor(random/1000)} seconds`)
    }, random);
};
colors.forEach(printArr);
```