# Nested setTimeout() calls don't run in the correct order in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to iterate over an array and then execute 2 steps (let's call them Step 1 and Step 2) in each iteration. There is supposed to be a delay between each iteration and between Step 1 and Step 2. For adding the delay, I'm using setTimeout() method.

Basically, something along the lines of -

For i from 0 to array.length

Do Step 1

Wait for 2-5 seconds

Do Step 2 and increment i

Wait for 5-9 seconds and continue the loop

Below is my code (from the related question - [How to run setTimeout() with a random interval in each iteration in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55247314/how-to-run-settimeout-with-a-random-interval-in-each-iteration-in-javascript)) -

```
function displayValue(){
   var l = ['a' , 'b', 'c'];
   var delay = 17000;
   var i = 0;
   function timerFunction(i){
      if(i === l.length)
          return;
      setTimeout(()=>{
         console.log("Step 1 - Iteration  - " + i + " - " + l[i] + "  -  " + new Date().getHours() + ":" + new Date().getMinutes() + ":" + new Date().getSeconds());
         setTimeout(() => {
           console.log("Step 2 - Iteration - " + i + " - " + l[i] + "  -  " + new Date().getHours() + ":" + new Date().getMinutes() + ":" + new Date().getSeconds());
           //i++ should probably be here but then i is never incremented
        }, 2000 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000));
     i++;
     timerFunction(i);
   }, delay);
   delay = 5000 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 3500);
   } 
   timerFunction(i);
 }

 displayValue();
```

When I run the above, Step 2 is printed before Step 1 for all iterations after the first and the loop runs past array.length. The output is something like -

Step 1 - Iteration  - 0 - a  -  9:17:14

Step 2 - Iteration - 1 - b  -  9:17:18

Step 1 - Iteration  - 1 - b  -  9:17:21

Step 2 - Iteration - 2 - c  -  9:17:24

Step 1 - Iteration  - 2 - c  -  9:17:28

Step 2 - Iteration - 3 - undefined  -  9:17:30

I suspect this is because, I need to increment i in the inner setTimeout(), but when I move `i++;` there, it stops incrementing altogether probably because it becomes a local variable in that method. Is there a way to pass i by reference in the inner setTimeout()? Or some other solution in case I'm completely off?

Comment: have you tried to make those variables out side of function global scope ?

Comment: What is your expected output? It is hard to understand what you want to do. For your case, you could probably calculate the delay time for all steps in the first place then dispatch all setTimeout at the same level at the same time.

Comment: Have you considered looking into javascript Iterators? It seems they will _VASTLY_ simplify the implementation of your code, since you just ask for the next item in a collection. You can do it in a loop, exit the loop, do something else, ask for the next item and get exactly what you want. It seems helpful here, since you could avoid all the horrible nested interval code. More here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols

Comment: In the mean time...The problem you've created for yourself is indeed a race condition. In order to use the same variable ( `i` in this case) in two bits of code that are both asynchronous in nature, you must wrap the inner function in a structure that is referred to as a closure. The easiest way to do that is with an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE).

Comment: @enhzflep I fail to see how an Iterator would help "*VASTLY simplify* [ing]" this code. They would still need two nested setTimeouts, iterating the Array is not the hard part here. Could you share an example? I guess I miss something.

Comment: @Kaiido - You're right, I was a little too enthusiastic about iterators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are continuing the loop from the first setTimeout callback, and that at this time, the second one still hasn't fired.

All you need is thus to make the recursive call to `timerFunction` from inside the second level timeout

```js
function displayValue() {
  var l = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
  var delay = 1000;
  timerFunction(0);

  function timerFunction(i) {
    if (i === l.length)
      return;

    setTimeout(() => { // level 1
      console.log("Step 1 - Iteration  - " + i + " - " + l[i] + "  -  " + new Date().getHours() + ":" + new Date().getMinutes() + ":" + new Date().getSeconds());
      // we start level2 timeout
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Step 2 - Iteration - " + i + " - " + l[i] + "  -  " + new Date().getHours() + ":" + new Date().getMinutes() + ":" + new Date().getSeconds());
        // only when this one is done, we start again
        timerFunction(++i);
      }, 500 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 500));
    }, delay);
    delay = 1000 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 800);
  }
}

displayValue();
```

But note that this doesn't correspond to your description of what should happen. Here it is:

```js
function displayValue() {
  var l = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
  timerFunction(0);

  function timerFunction(i) {
    if (i === l.length) {
      return;
    }
    // Do Step 1
    level1();

    function level1() {
      console.log("Step 1 - Iteration  - " + i + " - " + l[i] + "  -  " + new Date().getHours() + ":" + new Date().getMinutes() + ":" + new Date().getSeconds());
      // Wait for 2-5seconds (here /10)
      setTimeout(level2, 200 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 300));
    }

    function level2() {
      // Do Step2
      console.log("Step 2 - Iteration - " + i + " - " + l[i] + "  -  " + new Date().getHours() + ":" + new Date().getMinutes() + ":" + new Date().getSeconds());
      // and increment i
      i++;
      // wait for 5-9 seconds and continue the loop
      setTimeout(() => timerFunction(i), 500 + Math.round(Math.random() * 400));
    }

  }
}
displayValue();
```

And if you can use *async/await* syntax, then you can rewrite it a bit cleaner:

```js
displayValue();

function displayValue() {
  const l = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
  return iterate(0);

  async function iterate(i) {
    if(i >= l.length) return;
    step(1, i);
    await wait(200, 500);
    step(2, i);
    await wait(500, 900);
    return iterate(++i);
  }
  function step(type, index) {
    var d = new Date();
    console.log("Step " + type +
      " - Iteration  - " + index +
      " - " + l[index] +
      " -  " + d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes() + ":" + d.getSeconds()
    );  
  }
}
function wait(min, max=min) {
  const delay = min + Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min));
  return new Promise(res =>
    setTimeout(res, delay)
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the wonderful answer!! And thank you so much for the much much cleaner code and for the async/await variations. I had no idea async/await existed in javascript, the code became so much easier to follow with it. I wish I could give more than one upvotes!!