# setTimeout random time

Tags: javascript, twitch-api

Hello how can i change it to random time between 30-50sec?
I don't need new code or something just wanna edit this

```
client.on('chat', function(channel, user, message, self) {
    if (user.username == 'Cortex' && message === 'sar') {
        
        test();
        
    }
});


function test() 
{
    setInterval(function() {
        var spamMessage = 'KEK ';
        var toSpam = 'MingLee';
        for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            spamMessage += toSpam + ' '; 
        }
        client.say(channel, spamMessage)
    }, 30000);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run setTimeout() with a random interval in each iteration in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55247314/how-to-run-settimeout-with-a-random-interval-in-each-iteration-in-javascript) In short, you can use a recursive function.

Comment: `function sendMessage() { /* code */ window.setTimeout(sendMessage, randomNumber);  }` just use timeout and call the function over and over

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
client.on('chat', function(channel, user, message, self) {
    if (user.username == 'Cortex' && message === 'sar') {
        
        test();
        
    }
});


function test() 
{
    const min = 30000;
    const max = 50000;

  const time =  Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;

    setInterval(function() {
        var spamMessage = 'KEK ';
        var toSpam = 'MingLee';
        for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            spamMessage += toSpam + ' '; 
        }
        client.say(channel, spamMessage)
    }, time);
}
```

Comment: my guess OP wants it random each time, not same each time (not the downvote)